# Python не видит пакет при импорте

Tags: python, модули

Сделал веб проект и пришло время к пакетам, создал `__init__.py` где мне нужно, но почему-то ошибка импорта(`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ProstoToolsDashboard'`)

Структура директории:

```
┌ProstoToolsDashboard
│   app.py
│   config.py
│   __init__.py
└───core
    │   utils.py
    │   views.py
    │   __init__.py
    ├───static
    └───templates
```

app.py

```
from ProstoToolsDashboard.core.views import bp
```

views.py

```
from ProstoToolsDashboard.config import Config
from ProstoToolsDashboard.core.utils import Utils
from ProstoToolsDashboard.app import jinja
```

Comment: Скорее всего, активная директория не та, в которой находится `ProstoToolsDashboard`, а уровнем ниже, поэтому интерпретатор не видит пакет. А так, какой файл из этой структуры вы запускали? `app.py`?

Comment: Вы можете при запуске из `app` указать путь без пакета, т.е. `from core.views import bp`. Либо оставить как есть и в папке с `ProstoToolsDashboard` сделать файл и там можно будет обратиться к пакету, например: `from ProstoToolsDashboard import app`

Comment: @gil9red Да, я запускаю файл `app.py`

Comment: @gil9red Я уже это пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Вариант с `from core.views import bp` при запуске из `app.py` должен помочь, но нужно будет убрать из всех импортов `ProstoToolsDashboard`, т.к. пакет при таком запуске не будет виден. Смотрите, при импорте поиск выполняется из `sys.path` (и, кст, можно руками в эту переменную добавлять папки, в которых нужно искать модули или пакеты)

Comment: @gil9red насколько я помню правильнее будет `from .core.views import bp`

Comment: @gil9red Директория есть в `sys.path`

Comment: Повторюсь, если хотите чтобы был импорт как у вас и при этом вызывать из `ProstoToolsDashboard/app.py`, то папка должна быть родительская от `ProstoToolsDashboard`, тогда питон увидит эту папку, а в ней увидит `__init__.py` и поймет что это пакет. Сейчас, он запускается внутри `ProstoToolsDashboard` и не видит в ней такой пакет

Comment: @gil9red Объясните пожалуйста по-подробней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. В `__init__.py` были добавлены следующие строки:

```
from .config import Config
from .core.utils import Utils
from .app import jinja
from .app import session
from .app import app
```

А файле `views.py` импорты были изменены на такие:

```py
from ProstoToolsDashboard import Config
from ProstoToolsDashboard import Utils
from ProstoToolsDashboard import jinja, app
```